# Extending Headers web api causes bug in Safari

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add custom method in Header class.

```
class RequestModule extends Headers {
     customMethod() {}
   }

    this.customHeaders = new RequestModule({headers}) 
    this.customHeaders.customMethod()
```

When I'm trying to use this method, in Safari raised an error

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: this.customHeaders.customMethod is not a function. 
(In 'this.customHeaders.customMethod(options)', 'this.customHeaders.customMethod' is 
 undefined)`
```

When I debug this.customHeaders in Safari's console, I have following output:

```
append()
constructor: function()
delete()
entries()
forEach()
get()
has()
keys()
set()
values()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator)()
```

but in Chrome everything works as expected and custom methods created in RequestModule and returned to customHeaders

Is it specific Safari issue? How can I extend Headers class in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Remove those curly braces:

```js
this.customHeaders = new RequestModule({ headers })
//                                     ^ bad     ^ bad
```

ES2015 introduced a shorthand for [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions), and the [Headers constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/Headers) interprets a POJO as a dictionary of key-value pairs, where the keys are the names of HTTP headers.

So, with the curly braces, your line is equivalent to this:

```js
this.customHeaders = new Headers()
this.customHeaders.set('headers', headers)
```

The problem is that "Headers" is not an accepted HTTP header name, and, [per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers):

> **Note**: All of the Headers methods will throw a `TypeError` if you try to pass in a reference to a name that isn't a [valid HTTP Header name](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-header-name). The mutation operations will throw a `TypeError` if the header has an immutable [Guard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Guard). In any other failure case they fail silently.

<sup>*Links in original.*</sup>

I guess I'd expect your code to throw a `TypeError`, since it seems clear it would be interpreted as passing a reference to a name that isn't a valid HTTP Header name. But, based on the behavior you're reporting, and my own experimentation, it seems to be failing silently, as provided for by that note.

---

This works in Safari:

```js
class RequestModule extends Headers {
  customMethod() {
    console.log(`test`)
  }
}

let headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
  'X-My-Custom-Header': 'Zeke are cool'
}

let customHeaders = new RequestModule(headers)
customHeaders.customMethod()
```

Dinosaur comics [puts it pretty well](https://www.qwantz.com/index.php?comic=1178):

> Programming is for folks who are thrilled when a computer reminds them they're missing a bracket or semicolon